# which is more efficient way of doing something, using NSSet or Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nsset

I have a core data entity, which has a relationship to another entity.

`Entity A` has an `NSSet` which contains objects of `Entity B`. `Entity A` is stored as a property called `user` in a singleton available to every other class

Now, I want to display the latest 6 objects of `Entity B`, which has a property of type `NSDate` that is the gained date.

Which is the more efficient way of doing things:

1. Sorting the `NSSet` into an `NSArray`
2. Running a fetch request to get the latest 6 objects

Comment: If you already have objects in memory I would say that it should be much faster sorting that set than fetching it from database with some sort descriptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test it. It depends entirely on whether that relationship contents is already faulted into memory and how many items there are.

Already faulted AND small number of items should tend towards the set. not faulted OR large number of items towards Core Data (I.e. Fetch request with predicate).